# "grey out" folders and files which are ignored by git in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

When I have folders or files that are ignored by git then PHP storm "greys out" the files in the project panel. In this image node_modules is ignored:

[image]

Is there a way to do the same for Sublime text 2?

Comment: Looks like Sublime Text 3 does this by default now.

Comment: Whats the solution?